# Use ACF to add content to post type archive

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I'm trying to create a page with some custom fields (ACF) to display on a custom post type archive page. I tried to create a new page with the same slug as the custom post type archive (test.com/testimonials) and display the custom fields on that page.

I was hoping I could show the content of the custom fields on the testimonials archive page, but it doesn't seem to work. Can I accomplish the wanted result this way without creating a separate options page? This way it's easier for my client to find everything she needs.

Comment: Did you add the `get_field('testimonials')` functions on your page template?

Answer (score 0):

I tried another approach. I added an options sub page to the custom post type and added the custom fields to this options page.